# How to successfully import AVFoundation using Swift in Xcode 12 beta 3?

Tags: swift, macos, beta, xcode12

With Xcode 12 beta 3 calling:

```
import AVFoundation
```

in a Swift file causes the build to fail. The error text includes:

> Failed to build module 'AVFoundation' from its module interface; the
> compiler that produced it, [...], may have used features
> that aren't supported by this compiler.

Is there a workaround? (*reformulating as Q&A on SO to aid other developers on this beta)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`extension AVAudioSession.Location` needs to be marked as `unavailable` for **macOS**.

Edit the relevant **.swift-interface** file.  When installed in /Applications, this file should be found at:

```
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/swift/AVFoundation.swiftmodule/x86_64-apple-macos.swiftinterface
```

There are **2 locations** to change **from**:

```
@available(iOS 7.0, watchOS 2.0, tvOS 9.0, *)
extension AVAudioSession.Location {
```

**to**:

```
@available(OSX, unavailable)
@available(iOS 7.0, watchOS 2.0, tvOS 9.0, *)
extension AVAudioSession.Location {
```

Many thanks to users **eldevo** (Question) and **Gerrit** (Answer) on the Apple Developer Forums, see https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/655334